# Bootstrap Datepicker load max and min date using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to load the min date and max date for bootstrap datepicker through ajax calls

Bootstrap DatePicker config:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true,
        keyboardNavigation: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
        minDate: sdate, 
        maxDate: edate
    })
    .on('changeDate', function() {
        getMessageDate();
    });

});
```

Ajax to load min and max date in the configuration

```
var sdate;
var edate;

$(document).ready(function() {
(function () {
       var result;
       $.ajax({
            url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/IRSGetDate',
            async: false,  
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                result = data;
            },
            complete: function(){
                var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
                sdate = obj['start'];
                edate = obj['end'];

            },
            error: function(error,text,http){
                alert(error + " " + text + " " + http);
            }
        });
    })();
});
```

But it's still not working, am I doing something wrong?

Also can I add specific dates only to enable in the picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

few corrections made in your code

- changed ajax `method: 'GET'`
- changed `minDate` and `MaxDate` to [startDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate) and [endDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enddate)

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
(function () {
       var result;
       $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/doxkl',
            async: false,  
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                result = data;
            },
            complete: function(){
                sdate = result[0].start;
                edate = result[0].end;
                loadDatepicker(sdate,edate);
            },
            error: function(error,text,http){
                alert(error + " " + text + " " + http);
            }
        });
        function loadDatepicker(sdate,edate){
          $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            autoclose: true,
            keyboardNavigation : true ,
            todayHighlight:true,
            autoclose: true,
            startDate:sdate,
            endDate:edate
          })
            .on('changeDate', function() {
            getMessageDate();
          });
        }
    })();
});
```

---

in my following example i have set `"start": "08/08/2017"` and `"end": "08/28/2017"`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
(function () {
       var result;
       $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/doxkl',
            async: false,  
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                result = data;
            },
            complete: function(){
                sdate = result[0].start;
                edate = result[0].end;
    loadDatepicker(sdate,edate);
            },
            error: function(error,text,http){
                alert(error + " " + text + " " + http);
            }
        });
        function loadDatepicker(sdate,edate){
          $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            autoclose: true,
            keyboardNavigation : true ,
            todayHighlight:true,
            autoclose: true,
            startDate:sdate,
            endDate:edate
          })
            .on('changeDate', function() {
            getMessageDate();
          });
        }
    })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<input type="text" type="text" id="datepicker" />
```